# Laravel Model Relationships show Admin details from post

Tags: php, laravel

I'm creating a small social media where admin can posts to user's dashboard but having trouble with showing the admin details like profile picture to the posts

this is the error i got

```
Trying to get property 'profile_image' of non-object
```

Check my code

**Post.php** // my post model

```
 public function admin() 
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Admin');
}
```

**Admin.php** // my admin model

```
  public function post() 
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Post');
}
```

now on my user dashboard i would try to access my admin details using this code  `{{ $post->admin->profile_image }}`

Comment: What does `var_dump($post->admin)` return to you?

Comment: its says null sorry for late reply

Comment: Can only admin post posts? Maybe even a user can do on his dashboard. So, if that is the case, technically user is the owner of the post and hence you might be getting null when trying to fetch admin details for that post.

Comment: Nope only admin can post is this a problem on my model relationship?

Comment: and i use guards for my admin auth, can that cause a problem?

Comment: Whether only admin can post or not depends up on what you are building. Can you show your table rows by editing your post?

Answer (score 1):

You get that error because `$post->admin is null` You must be check `$post->admin` empty or not

```
{{ $post->admin ? $post->admin->profile_image : ''}}
```

Comment: it just return null is this a problem on my relationship or i can do this what i want with other methods?

Comment: you must be check your relations